# how to write this in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using godaddy and what I want to do is when someone types in a domain address I want it to automatically redirect to a folder rather than  placing the files on the root so its more organised.

How do I write this in .htaccess?

Comment: Even better: how about programming questions and not web/DNS administration ones?

Comment: .htaccess questions are regularly allowed on here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use GoDaddy for your DNS only, or for your web hosting as well? Their economy plan does not allow you to host multiple websites (http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/hosting/shared.asp?ci=9009)

GoDaddy has a nice online help, you should take a look: http://help.godaddy.com/article/4688

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) subfolder/$1 [L]
```

The L is needed so that if there are other rules they don't get executed (think infinite loop); this is written as a catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Rewrite**

Unless a condition exists the Rewrite will not do stuff. Here's a code that will actually work in no subfolder is specified. e.g http://domain.com will be redirected to http://domain.com/subfolder/somefile

You can also point it to a subfolder and not a file, just remove the somefile.php and your set. Remember to change the value of "DOMAIN" and "SUBFOLDER"

```
#Turns the engines on!
rewriteEngine on
# Checks Condition, "Does it have a subfolder specified?"
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
# Does its Rewrite Magic
rewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/subfolder/somefile.php [R,L]
```

Comment: i would also add a code to the redirect [L,R=301] for example